# Trying to set-up ubuntu on a Sony Vaio VGN-B100B

Tags: vaio, sony

Does anyone have any hints/suggestions on which flavor of ubuntu would work on: 
Sony Vaio; 512M RAM; 106G HDD; VGN-B100B; PCG-5B1L; currently running WinXP; Intel Centrino; Intel Pentium M 755 / 2 GHz; Bus speed=400 MHz; chipset Intel 855GME.
Wanted lubuntu but this doesn't meet specs. Thanks YouTube posts, define parameters in the beginning... . JS
Any help would be appreciated.